# Custom value range for winform button property

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've got a range of custom buttons I've made that all have a variable that relates to a dictionary key..

My question is how do I set valid inputs for this variable in the properties of the button? Currently it is just set from a string as this is the variable type

```
[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue("None"),Category("Data"), ]
    public string UnitType
```

Ideally it would be nice to be able to set this value in a similar way to setting BorderStyle or FlatStyle

Comment: So why not make the property an Enum like BorderStyle or FlatStyle?

Comment: didn't realise that was possible, thanks!

Comment: @StuartDunkeld - would you mind making your comment an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your property an Enum like [BorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.borderstyle.aspx) or [FlatStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flatstyle.aspx)